# Coded UI automation not working in Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

I have installed the following:

> 1. Visual Studio 2017
> 2. Chrome Browser - Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)
> 3. Chrome Driver- 2.40

While running a coded UI automation in Visual Studios, I am unable to to run it successfully. It doesn't move past the main page.

It throws the following error:

Only local connections are allowed.

> ERROR: gpu_process_transport_factory.cc

Comment: paste your code in the question description.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `disable-gpu` option via `ChromeOptions`:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArgument("disable-gpu"); 

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you'll also want to include the `--disable-gp`u flag if you're running on Windows.

Comment: Where to add the --disable-gpu flag?